# Determinant question about exchanging rows & columns.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let A be a $4 × 4$ matrix, and choose $i, j, k, l \in [4]$ with $i \ne j$ and $k \ne l$. Let $B$ be the matrix obtained from $A$ by exchanging the $i^{th}$ and $j^{th}$ rows, and by exchanging the $k^{th}$ and $l^{th}$ columns. Determine how det $A$ and det $B$ relate.

Answer (score 0):

Swapping columns (or rows) when you calculate the determinant of a matrix changes its sign. One swap = one sign change.

So, if you swap the rows and columns when you calculate $\det(A)$ in your case, you will actually be calculating $\det(B)$, since there are two swaps.

So you have :

$$\det(A) = \det(B)$$